How can I scrape all the education and experince details of user profile on Linkedin
So Im using voyager api to get profile infor on linkedin , also i have another api called linkedin-api to scrape linkedin profile. but the problem is while im getting all the data, i only get the first 5 experiences even if there are more than 5 experiences and I only get first 3 educations even if there are more. It seems the response is paginated but im not not able to access the remaining education and experince details.
Thats the response showing the pagination im just showing a snippet of the json,
"positionGroupView": {
"paging": {
"start": 0,
"count": 5,
"total": 9,
"links": []
},.
Now how can I access all the education and experince details. do i need to change the end points or anything else. Would love some help here! Much Thanks
here are the necessary docs: scrape linkedin data

Linkedin api end points:


import requests
import json

def get_all_experiences(company_id):
    # Properly defined headers
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "csrf-token": "ajax:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  # Placeholder for the CSRF token
    }

    company_link = f'https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/identity/profiles/{company_id}/profileView'

    all_experiences = []
    start = 0
    count = 5  # The number of items to retrieve per request

    with requests.Session() as s:
        # Ensure these tokens are valid
        s.cookies['li_at'] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        s.cookies['JSESSIONID'] = "ajax:xxxxxxxxxxx"
        
        # Update headers to include the csrf-token from JSESSIONID
        s.headers.update(headers)

        while True:
            # Add pagination parameters to the URL
            paginated_link = f"{company_link}?start={start}&count={count}"

            # Make the GET request
            response = s.get(paginated_link)

            # Handle potential errors
            if response.status_code == 200:
                response_dict = response.json()
                
                # Assuming experiences are found in response_dict['positionGroupView']['elements']
                experiences = response_dict.get('positionGroupView', {}).get('elements', [])
                
                # Append retrieved experiences to the all_experiences list
                all_experiences.extend(experiences)

                # Get pagination info
                paging = response_dict.get('positionGroupView', {}).get('paging', {})
                total = paging.get('total', 0)

                # Break the loop if we've retrieved all experiences
                if start + count >= total:
                    break
                
                # Update the start index for the next iteration
                start += count
            else:
                print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
                return None

    return all_experiences

# Example usage
experiences = get_all_experiences('adrian-von-lewinski')
print(json.dumps(experiences, indent=2))




